# Potential Drop caused by internal resisitance

Tags: electric-circuits

The terminal potential of a cell is less than the EMF when a current is flowing through the circuit.

EMF is said to be the work done by some non-electrostatic force which 'pumps' the charge to a high potential. While pumping this charge through a battery, the charges face some internal resisitance and loose some of their potential energy inside the cell before even leaving the positive terminal. Why is this not the case when the circuit is open or the cell is in an isolated state. Charge would still face some internal resistance during the process of charge accumulation right ?

Comment: Because V = I * R, when I=0 then V=0

Answer (score 1):

> Charge would still face some internal resistance during the process of charge accumulation right ?

There will still be some inefficiency in separating the charges, and delivering electrons to the anode. This will generate some heat within the cell when it is first assembled.

But, since this is an open circuit scenario, the chemical reaction will simply proceed further until the potential difference between the terminals is equal to the cell potential, and the system is in equilibrium.

Since there's no circuit attached to the cell to draw off charge, there's no need for the chemical reaction in the cell to continue, so no further loss of energy (ignoring leakage currents between the electrodes), and so the cell only reaches equilibrium when the potential difference is equal to the cell potential (aka the battery emf), not before.